# Android - Firebase remote config cache on app update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

When I update my app version, will the firebase remote config cache resets and fetches new values or uses the existing cache, until the cache expires on set time

Comment: Hi Rosário, what was the behavior you were expecting? That the cache should be reset on app update?

Comment: yes.. looks like it wont as per answer provided

Comment: your question is on #AskFirebase... cool
https://youtu.be/gvRe-C7ZtDc?t=2m54s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't.
It fetches new values after the cache timeout and the cache stays even after an App update.

Though, you can call `fetch(Long)` with a timeout in seconds that is significant smaller than the default value but [according to the Google Blog, this might be risky](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/firebase-remote-config-loading.html).

A smaller timeout might be used if you write some code that decides that this is the first app start after an update, but `while you can reduce this cache time somewhat, if you start making network calls too frequently, your app might start getting throttled, either by the client, or the Remote Config service.` *(from the blog post linked above)*